# Pegar último id inserido no mysql com php

Tags: php, mysql

tenho a seguinte query de inclusão de cadastros

```
mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT into cadastro set nome='$nome',telefone='$fone',cep='$cep',secao='$categoria'");
```

como faço para não ter que dar um select no ultimo dado inserido para pegar o id gerado ?
pois ja tive problemas com vários usuários colocando informações no sistema ao mesmo tempo e retornou valor errado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apesar de ser um post duplicado você pega da seguinte forma

```
$idInserido=mysqli_insert_id($conexao);
```

Comment: aff pra q negativar a resposta?

Comment: Achei que a resposta foi boa. Só faltou complementar um pouquinho com a query, etc .. Poderia ter aproveitado o código da pergunta. O pessoal aqui marca em cima. Mas ganhou o meu upvote para neutralizar. ;D