# O U do CRUD não consigo pegar o ID e editar o realizar o Update

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-update, crud, id

Pessoal preciso de uma luz para desenrolar um TIMESHEET.

Tenho o seguinte codigo.

```
<form method="post" action="includes/input.php">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="send('login');" value="login" >Default</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="send('break');" value="break" >Default</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="send('breakout');" value="breakout" >Default</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="send('logout');" value="logout" >Default  </button>
    </form>
```

Esse formulario, chama perfeitamente as paginas. O Problema é que o primeiro Submit é um INSERT INTO que funciona perfeitamente enviando quatro datas para o banco via Mysqli com a função NOW().

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO registros (id, re, login, inbreak, outbreak, logout) VALUES ('', '$re', now(), now(), now(), now())";
```

A terceira coluna com a função Now() indica a hora de entrada do operador na linha de produção, a quarta coluna a entrada do break e assim por diante, eu preciso de ajuda para entender como eu realizo o update dessas colunas, mas não estou conseguindo capturar o ID para realizar o update.

Segue o codigo da pagina que seria para o update da quarta coluna.

```
$id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
var_dump($id);$re = '';
$sql = "UPDATE registros SET breakin = NOW() WHERE id = $id;"
```

Agradeço antecipadamente.

Answer (score 0):

o seu

```
$id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
```

esta errado vc precisa inserir a conexção do db no comando

```
$id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

Comment: Vou tentar, Obrigado.

Comment: Resultado do teste.
Esse comando espera somente um argumento.
Warning: mysqli_insert_id() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/time/break.php on line 9

Comment: me perdoe errei a função, vc só deve incluir a conecção , mais nada. logo apos o comando `mysqli_query($con,$sql);` vc consegue fazer o `$id = mysqli_insert_id($con); `

Comment: havia um outro post que respondi com o mesmo problema que você: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151395/pegar-%C3%BAltimo-id-inserido-no-mysql-com-php